# Adding custom claims (for authorization) to Principal on Client side

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been able to successfully implement my own IdentityServer4 authentication server on .net core 3.1 and I have a client web application connecting to it. The client is successfully receiving an access token and an id. The token contains all the user identifying information.

My next objective is to add the privileges that the user has within the client to the HttpContext.User as claims right after I get the token before any other page is rendered. The privileges are stored in the database associated to a user by the subjectId.

I am in need of help on where to look to be able to add those claims so that my authorization policies can work with the claims in the principal. I would like the process to execute everytime a token is issued.

P.S. I am using a code flow for Identity server with GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true and SaveTokens = true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using TokenValidated Event

```
    public class CustomJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    public override async Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var claims = context.Principal.Claims.ToList();
        claims.Add(new Claim("key", "value"));
        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer"));        }
}
```

Then register it in startup

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
              ...
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
                options.EventsType = typeof(CustomJwtBearerEvents);
            });
```

Comment: So thank you this sort of got me in the right direction. I ended up using this article based on the information you provided (https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Profile sevise in identityServer4:

```
 services .AddIdentityServer(x =>
            {
                x.IssuerUri = "null";
                x.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
            })
.
.
.          
              .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

This is a good reference:http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html
And ProfileService Can be like this code template:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;


    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;

    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Subject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context.Subject));

        var subjectId = subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid subject identifier");

        var claims = GetClaimsFromUser(user,subject);
        context.IssuedClaims = claims.Result.ToList();
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Subject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context.Subject));

        var subjectId = subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);

        context.IsActive = false;

        if (user != null)
        {
            if (_userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
            {
                var security_stamp = subject.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "security_stamp").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                if (security_stamp != null)
                {
                    var db_security_stamp = await _userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                    if (db_security_stamp != security_stamp)
                        return;
                }
            }

            context.IsActive =
                !user.LockoutEnabled ||
                !user.LockoutEnd.HasValue ||
                user.LockoutEnd <= DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaimsFromUser(ApplicationUser user,ClaimsPrincipal subject)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.Id),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, user.UserName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)

        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Name))
            claims.Add(new Claim("name", user.Name));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LastName))
            claims.Add(new Claim("last_name", user.LastName));


        return claims;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be in Identity Server where the privileges are not stored. I would need something on the client side that would be able to retrieve the SubjectId and add additional claims to the token based on client information.